# python re.search (regex) to search words who have pattern like {{world}} only

Tags: python, regex, matching

I have on HTML file in which I have inserted the custom tags like `{{name}}`, `{{surname}}`. Now I want to search the tags who exactly match the pattern like `{{world}}` only not even `{world}}`, `{{world}`, `{world}`, `{ word }`, `{{ world }}`, etc.
  I wrote the small code for the

```
re.findall(r'\{(\w.+?)\}', html_string)
```

It returns the words which follow the pattern {{world}} ,{world},{world}}
that I don't want. I want to match exactly the {{world}}. Can anybody please guide me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um, shouldn't the regex be:

```
'\{\{(\w.+?)\}\}'
```

Ok, after the comments, I understand your requirements more:

```
'\{\{\w+?\}\}'
```

should work for you.

Basically, you want {{any nnumber of word characters including underscore}}. You don't even need the lazy match in this case actually so you may remove th `?` in the expression.

Something like `{{keyword1}} other stuff {{keyword2}}` will not match as a whole now.

To get only the keyword without getting the {{}} use below:

```
'(?<=\{\{)\w+?(?=\}\})'
```

Comment: no this will also match the pattern of {word}} {{word} like that...:(

Comment: How will it match? Note the explicit two curly braces in the regex

Comment: it should match exactly the pattern {{world}} like that only

Comment: q = 'html>\n <head>\n </head>\n <title>\n </title>\n <body>\n  <h1>\n   T - Shirts\n  </h1>\n  <img src="Tshirts/skull_headphones_tshirt.jpg" />\n  <img src="shirts/star-wars-t-shirts-6.jpeg" />\n  <h2>\n   we - we - we\n  </h2>\n   {{unsubscribe}} -- {{tracking_beacon} -- {web_url}} -- {name} \n </body>\n</html>\n'

Comment: Have you tried the above pattern that I have given in your code?

Comment: @Shashi: this pattern should work because he made the inner part a lazy match rather than a greedy one. That's what the ? mark does after a * or +.

Comment: I think this i work re.findall('({{\w+}})', html_string)  post given by ʇsәɹoɈ. I should try this before sorry for my laziness

Comment: @Justin, it was already a lazy match in his question, I assume from his example, that the problem is that it matches `{{tracking_beacon} -- {web_url}}`

Comment: sorry for that i didnt clear it it should match {{unsubscribe}} word only..thanks for comments

Comment: Phew, I think what you are getting at. Update my answer

Comment: the solution above giving the correct matching pattern like {{unsbscribe}} but i want to get on that word unsubscribe not with the {{ ,}} ,i hope i clear

Comment: this pattern \{\{(\w[^\{\}]+?)\}\}   will use full to get the word without the curly bres

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer again. You have make the {{}} non capturing

Comment: Mark as answer if that is what you want!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match doubled curly brackets, you should specify them in your regex:

```
re.findall(r'\{\{(\w[^}]?)\}\}', html_string)
```

Comment: this will also match the pattern like {word}} {{world} like that that should not match

Comment: See my edit. In that case you have to specify "not }" instead of just using a simple dot.

Comment: Achim, you'll need some kind of quantifier in your regex, as currently it will only match a single word character, and an optional char that is not '}', between the double braces.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
re.findall('{{(\w+)}}', html_string)
```

Or, if you want the curly braces included in the results:

```
re.findall('({{\w+}})', html_string)
```

If you're trying to accomplish html templating, though, I recommend using a [good template engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).

Answer (score 2):

This will match no curly braces within your result, do you want that?

```
'\{\{(\w[^\{\}]+?)\}\}'
```

http://rubular.com/r/79YwR13MS0

Answer (score 2):

You say the other answers don't work, but they seem to for me:

```
>>> import re
>>> html_string = '{{realword}} {fake1}} {{fake2} {fake3} fake4'
>>> re.findall(r'\{\{(\w.+?)\}\}', html_string)
['realword']
```

If it doesn't work for you, you'll need to give more details.

**Edit**: How about the following? Getting rid of the dot (`.`) and using only `\w` also allows you to use greedy qualifiers and works for the example HTML from your comment:

```
>>> html_string = 'html>\n <head>\n </head>\n <title>\n </title>\n <body>\n <h1>\n T - Shirts\n </h1>\n <img src="March-Tshirts/skull_headphones_tshirt.jpg" />\n <img src="/March-Tshirts/star-wars-t-shirts-6.jpeg" />\n <h2>\n we - we - we\n </h2>\n {{unsubscribe}} -- {{tracking_beacon} -- {web_url}} -- {name} \n </body>\n</html>\n'
>>> re.findall(r'\{\{(\w+)\}\}', html_string)
['unsubscribe']
```

The `\w` matches alphanumeric characters and the underscore; if you need to match more characters you could add it to a set (e.g., `[\w\+]` to also match the plus sign).

Comment: You are right this is working for your example but when i tried with eg:
html_string = 'html>\n <head>\n </head>\n <title>\n </title>\n <body>\n  <h1>\n   T - Shirts\n  </h1>\n  <img src="March-Tshirts/skull_headphones_tshirt.jpg" />\n  <img src="/March-Tshirts/star-wars-t-shirts-6.jpeg" />\n  <h2>\n   we - we - we\n  </h2>\n   {{unsubscribe}} -- {{tracking_beacon} -- {web_url}} -- {name} \n </body>\n</html>\n'

it giving the result:
 ['unsubscribe', 'tracking_beacon} -- {web_url']